# German special characters put into Byte array

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, encoding, special-characters

I'm doing encrypt algotythm right now and I need to encrypt german words also. So I have to encrypt for example characters like: ü,ä or ö.

Inside I've got a function:

```
private static byte[] getBytesArray(string data)
{
    byte[] array;
    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding asciiEncoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
    array = asciiEncoding.GetBytes(data);            
    return array;
}
```

But when data is "ü", byte returned in array is 63 (so "?"). How can I return ü byte?

I also tried:

```
private static byte[] MyGetBytesArray(string data)
{
    byte[] array;
    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding asciiEncoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();

    Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding(true, true);
    array = enc.GetBytes(data);

    return array;
}
```

but in this case I get 2 bytes in array: 195 and 188.

Comment: Use `UTF8Encoding` instead of `ASCIIEncoding` both in encoding and decoding.

Comment: ASCII by definition only goes up to 7Fh, and such German characters are above `7Fh` (please verify). Can you try `Encoding.Default` instead ?

Comment: You can use 1141 as encoding according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx

Comment: @AngshumanAgarwal `Encoding.Default` is always a bad choice, since that is machine-specific

Comment: @Marshall yes, it is perfectly expected to get 2 bytes back for that character in the array. If you get rid of `asciiEncoding` (which isn't used), your second example will work. Personally I'd just use `return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);`, but same thing really. What value were you expecting? and: why?

Comment: @Marc: Thanks for your feedback. Point noted.

Comment: @t3hn00b code-pages are always a bad compromise - the range of special characters is very limited **even in** the most appropriate one. Something like UTF-8 is far preferable.

Comment: Thanks for your all answers. So these two bytes (195 and 188) are correct. Now I get it.. but that is not a good information for my algorythm.. I need to use Blowfish to encrypt and decrypt string with german characters..

edit. Sorry, it works perfectly. Thanks guys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please replace **System.Text.ASCIIEncoding** with **System.Text.UTF8Encoding** and rename the encoding object accordingly in your first example. ASCII basically does not support german characters, so this is why you'll have to use some other encoding (UTF-8 seems to be the best idea here).

Please take a look here: [ASCII Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and here: [UTF-8 Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
System.Text.Encoding utf_8 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

// This is our Unicode string:
string s_unicode = "abcéabc";

// Convert a string to utf-8 bytes.
byte[] utf8Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s_unicode);

// Convert utf-8 bytes to a string.
string s_unicode2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
```